# Does an APNS Token converted FCM Token expire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

FCM is used for notifications within my projects and I have to know, if the FCM token extracted from an APNS token using the batchImport endpoint ever changes.
Are there any mapping at firebase, that has an fcm token mapped to a specific apns token or are apns tokens converted to fcm tokens based on an algorithm?

To explain you my concerns. On every startup of my ios app, I'm checking if the apns token had changed and compare it to my local apns token from the previous start, just to call my backend to retrieve a new fcm token for the new apns token if a change had found place.

So what I am basically trying to figure out is, whether the fcm token could get updated, whilst the apns token remained the same? FCM's docs say, that it never expires, unless the app id had changed, the user restored the application on another device or reinstalled the app. How is it with the apns converted fcm tokens. Does it apply with those too?